# Django Passing Multiple Views from Different Apps to the Same Template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I have a django shop application where all the Products are listed on one page via listview (no individual product pages). But my cart is rendered on a different app/template. When products are added to the cart they go to the other cart template. How can I combine the views into one? Thanks in advance.

Carts App views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from catalogue.models import Product
from .models import Cart
# Create your views here.


def cart_home(request):
    cart_obj, new_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
    return render(request, "carts/carts.html", {"cart": cart_obj})


def cart_update(request):
    product_id = request.POST.get('product_id')
    if product_id is not None:
        try:
            product_obj = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
        except Product.DoesNotExist:
            print("Product is gone")
            return redirect("cart:home")
    cart_obj, new_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
    if product_obj in cart_obj.products.all():
        cart_obj.products.remove(product_obj)
    else:
        cart_obj.products.add(product_obj)
    return redirect("cart:home")
```

This is views.py from Catalogue app

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.shortcuts import render
from . import models
from .models import Product
from carts.models import Cart

class ProductListView(ListView):
    model = models.Product
    template_name = "catalogue/catalogue.html"

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProductListView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)

        cart_obj, new_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(self.request)
        context['cart'] = cart_obj
        cat_appetizers = Product.objects.filter(category__name='Appetizers')
        cat_alltimefavourites = Product.objects.filter(category__name='All Time Favourites')
        cat_baltidishes = Product.objects.filter(category__name='Balti Dishes')
        cat_biryanidishes = Product.objects.filter(category__name='Biryani Dishes')
        cat_bread = Product.objects.filter(category__name='Bread')
        cat_drinks = Product.objects.filter(category__name='Drinks')
        cat_grillroastdishes = Product.objects.filter(category__name='Grill & Roast Dishes')
        cat_housespecials = Product.objects.filter(category__name='House Specials')
        cat_oldfavourites = Product.objects.filter(category__name='Old Favourites')
        cat_rice = Product.objects.filter(category__name='Rice')
        cat_setmeals = Product.objects.filter(category__name='Set Meals')
        cat_sidedishes = Product.objects.filter(category__name='Side Dishes')
        cat_sundries = Product.objects.filter(category__name='Sundries')
        cat_vegetariandishes = Product.objects.filter(category__name='Vegetarian Dishes')
        context.update({'cat_appetizers': cat_appetizers })
        context.update({'cat_alltimefavourites': cat_alltimefavourites })
        context.update({'cat_baltidishes': cat_baltidishes })
        context.update({'cat_biryanidishes': cat_biryanidishes })
        context.update({'cat_bread': cat_bread })
        context.update({'cat_drinks': cat_drinks })
        context.update({'cat_grillroastdishes': cat_grillroastdishes })
        context.update({'cat_housespecials': cat_housespecials })
        context.update({'cat_oldfavourites': cat_oldfavourites })
        context.update({'cat_rice': cat_rice })
        context.update({'cat_setmeals': cat_setmeals })
        context.update({'cat_sidedishes': cat_sidedishes })
        context.update({'cat_sundries': cat_sundries })
        context.update({'cat_vegetariandishes': cat_vegetariandishes })
        return context
```

Comment: Question is not clear enough, what is that you are trying to achieve? What do you mean by combine the views!!

Comment: there are two views from different apps, I need to render to the same URL

Comment: So you want single route, which will displays both cart and catalogue?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it

Comment: option 1) create a new template which follows the layout you want, probably involves some javascript too (to add dynamically to cart). In the view, you need to return all those objects which existing views returns (as per your template)

Comment: option 2), create a new view with an associated template. template is two iframes (sigh) with one of the given routes in each frame. then some javascript to auto refresh, and fix up ui etc.